# JVM 16 with Z GC doesn't release memory back to OS (Linux)

Tags: java, linux, memory-management, jvm

I found strange behavior of my java app on Linux

OS: Fedora 34 (Kernel 5.12.7)
JDK: OpenJDK 16.0.1
GC: ZGC
Run app with:  -XX:+UseZGC -Xmx1G -XX:+ZUncommit -XX:ZUncommitDelay=30

ZUncommit should be enabled by default, but to be sure added this flag. Also reduced delay just for testing.
So after stress test on Linux my app takes about 900mb (check via system monitor) and never release ram back to the OS (but heap can be about only 100 mb). BUT on Windows everything is ok. After 5-10 min app release the ram and takes about 150-200 mb.
I have microservices and for me it's very important to release ram back. But Linux prefer kill my app instead get ram back

Comment: Please show GC logs and Native Memory Tracking stats